# How to send email to multiple recipients using drupal_mail?

Tags: emails

I am using drupal_mail to send email,

```
$to = 'email@email.com';
drupal_mail('$module_name', $key, $to, language_default(), $params = array('username' => 'Tanvir'), $from = NULL, $send = TRUE);
```

I want to send email to multiple email addresses at once. Should I be doing this?

```
$to  = array('one@email.com', 'two@email.com', 'three@email.com',);
drupal_mail('$module_name', $key, $to, language_default(), $params = array('username' => 'Tanvir'), $from = NULL, $send = TRUE);
```

Comment: check this post, http://dropbucket.org/node/308

Comment: Hey Tanvir, maybe consider accepting a different answer. The currently accepted answer entails the risk of running out of memory or time limit when processing many thousand emails like that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The to-parameter to `drupal_mail` is a string, not an array.  But you can have as many receipent as you like in the the e-mails "to" string, provided they're separated by commas.

So to send the same mail to multiple recipients, do the following:

```
$to  = 'one@email.com,two@email.com,three@email.com';
drupal_mail('$module_name', $key, $to, language_default(), $params = array('username' => 'Tanvir'), $from = NULL, $send = TRUE);
```

Se also [API documentation for `drupal_mail`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7)

Comment: i only say that when i try `$to  = 'one@email.com, two@email.com, three@email.com';` I receive only one email, but when I try `$to  = 'one@email.com,two@email.com,three@email.com';` without spaces I received all emails!

Answer (score 1):

According to PHP doc you can send only one letter via one call of function drupal_mail. So, you should use cycle.
Example

```
$to  = array('one@email.com', 'two@email.com', 'three@email.com',);
foreach ($to as $email) {
  drupal_mail('$module_name', $key, $email, language_default(), $params = array('username' => 'Tanvir'), $from = NULL, $send = TRUE);
}
```

Comment: See the solution below from @FreeRadical for a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: I updated my message to avoid confusing. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [hook_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7) to send multiple receipients by passing:

```
$params = array();
$params['cc'][] = 'abc@ex.org'
drupal_mail('$module_name', 'custom_key', $to, language_default(), $params = array('username' => 'Tanvir'), $from = NULL, $send = TRUE);


//hook will be the module name

function hook_mail($key,&$message,$params) {

  if ($key == 'custom_key') {
    $message['headers']['cc'] = $params['cc'];
    //.
    //.
    //.
    //.
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read drupal_mail function documentation then you'd see '$to' param accepts string not an array in certain formats like:

1. user@example.com
2. user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com
3. User
4. User , Another User

So, we can easily convert your $to array into required format using implode function and hence you'll be to send email to multiple recipients in one go. Here's the code:

```
$to  = array('one@email.com', 'two@email.com', 'three@email.com',);

//To change array('one@email.com', 'two@email.com', 'three@email.com',)  -> 'one@email.com, two@email.com, three@email.com' use implode

$to_str = implode(",", $to);

drupal_mail('$module_name', $key, $to_str, language_default(), $params = array('username' => 'Tanvir'), $from = NULL, $send = TRUE);
```